# after submtting a form how do I get the page to reload at the same scroll down distance as before?

Tags: html, forms, scroll

I have a page which has several forms on it. So you scroll down the page to see which ever one you want then you click to submit the form and the page reloads once the stuff behind the scenes happens.

But the page will reload and show the very top of the page. Is there a way to remember where on the page the user was on the page before the page was submitted?

thanks

Comment: `<form action="#jumphere"...` and in your HTML further down add `<a name="jumphere"></a>` to the place you want it to jump to; *basically.*

Comment: Please refrain from tag-spam.  [tag:css], [tag:php], [tag:javascript] and [tag:jquery] have nothing to do with your OP as you've written it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `id` of an element and append it to your link like

```
action="<your link>#formID"
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"Is there a way to remember where on the page the user was on the page before the page was submitted?"*

*Yes there is*. There are a few ways to achieve this. One method is to use [**anchors**](http://help.typepad.com/anchor-tags.html).

`<form action="#jumphere"` (*as an example*)

And in your HTML further down, add `<a name="jumphere"></a>` to the place you want it to jump to.

Here is an example with two forms: (you can modify the anchors' placements to your liking)

```
<p align="left">
<a name="form1"></a>
<br>
Form 1
</p>
<form method="POST" action="handler.php#form1">
  <p align="left">Name: <input type="text" name="name" size="20"><br>
  <br>
  Email: <input type="text" name="email" size="20"><br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Submit">
  <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset1">
  </p>
</form>
<p align="left">
<a name="form2"></a>
<br>

Form 2
</p>
<form method="POST" action="handler.php#form2">

  <p align="left">Name 2: <input type="text" name="name" size="20"><br>
  <br>
  Email 2: <input type="text" name="email" size="20"><br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Submit">
  <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset2">
  </p>
</form>
```